# php ldap terminal services profile path

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I've written a php page to change user's names when they get married etc using ldap, however I've just noticed that [ldap_get_entries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-entries.php) does not return the TS Profile path (`msTSProfilePath`). Does anyone know how I can get this so I can change it to the new name? (we are changing the user's homedirectory to the new name which includes the TS Profile). Searched here & google, both return 0 results

example code:

```
$server = "eng-ads-01s.eng.company.co.uk";
$dn = "DC=eng,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk";$user = "CN=User Name,OU=Users,OU=Helpdesk,OU=Group IT,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk";
//user password
$psw = "Password";
$ds=ldap_connect($server);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3); 
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0); 
$r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw); 
// performing search
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $search);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);  
print_r($data);
```

$data doesn't return the TS profile path even though it's in AD

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your code to see what contrxt we are talking about?

Comment: code added to original post

Comment: Is that on a Windows2003-Server? I've found https://forums.netiq.com/archive/index.php/t-7258.html which seems to state that the ```msTSProfilePath``` is stored together with other stuff in the BLOB-field ```userparameters```.

Comment: thank you @heiglandreas, we are on 2003, that helps a lot